# Deploying an Eclipse Spring MVC Project to Tomcat without stopping and starting

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I have inherited a Spring project that consists of 3 different distinct projects.  There is a series of ANT files that build the project and deploy it to a Tomcat. There is an ANT target called 'build' that does this.

The trouble is that when the tomcat server is running, I can't deploy - instead I have to stop the server, deploy and then start the server again.

I noticed that the 'VMware vFabric' server seems to support what I want when I create a spring project via a MVC template in STS.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this for an existing Spring MVC project that uses an ANT build?

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you getting?

Also is your ANT script like as suggested by Tomcat docs? This has worked for me without any problems.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AntDeploy

Comment: The ant files are quite complex, I didn't see anything like the link but I did see <deploy environment="${environment}" />, I would rather not edit the ANT script to be honest because I am using it with other people.

Comment: If your ant script not using remote deployment and doing some file based deployment then surely you will be stuck where some files are locked by the process.

Comment: Better option is to refactor the scripts and use what the tomcat docs suggest to deploy your war. In case of your custom deployment I can only help if I know what issue you facing.